# How to load data in qlikview with loop and not existent fields?

Tags: for-loop, scripting, business-intelligence, qlikview

I am trying to load data in qlikview with a for loop, where 1,2 and 3 are the fieldnames:

```
for a = 1 to 3
Test:
    LOAD [$(a)] 
    FROM [$(Path)\File.xlsx]
(ooxml, no labels, table is [Sheet]);

next
```

The problem is that I don`t know which of the fields 1,2 and 3 is actually existent in
the table. So if 2 is not in the table I get the "field not existent" error. Is there a
possibility that qlikview recognizes that the filed is not existent and therefore does
not try to load this field?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
set errormode = 0
for a = 1 to 3
Test:
    LOAD [$(a)] 
    FROM [$(Path)\File.xlsx]
(ooxml, no labels, table is [Sheet]);

next
set errormode = 1
```

this way if the field is not in the table then it just ignores it and continues the loop